# I can't set focus on the input

Tags: reactjs

I have this component https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-u7rw2w?file=App.tsx

When I click and call toggleInputCardName, I see in the console "NO inputRef.current null false". At the same time, an input is rendered on the page and above it I see "null inputRef true".

I tried using useEffect, but the result is the same.

How to understand this? IsInputCardName is simultaneously true and false?
How to set focus on the input in toggleInputCardName?

Comment: All three answers work. So which one to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try useCallback

```
const inputRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node) {
      node.focus();
      node.setSelectionRange(node.value.length, node.value.length);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Nice idea! Never thought about using a callback ref for this

Answer (score 1):

It is because the setState is async.
I think about 2 possibilities.

First one :

```
  const toggleInputCardName = () => {
    setInputCardNameVisibity(!isInputCardName);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      console.log('YES inputRef.current', inputRef.current);
      inputRef.current.focus();
      inputRef.current.select();
    } else {
      console.log('NO inputRef.current', inputRef.current, isInputCardName);
    }
  }, [isInputCardName]);
```

Second one, you could simply add autofocus on the input and don't use ref :

```
<input
  className="input-card-title"
  type="text"
  value="value"
  autoFocus
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `useLayoutEffect`:

```
  const toggleInputCardName = () => {
    setInputCardNameVisibity(!isInputCardName)
  }

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!inputRef.current) return
    inputRef.current.focus()
    inputRef.current.select()
  }, [isInputCardName])
```

The reason it doesn't work in the handler or in a plain `useEffect` is that they are executing before the input is actually written to the DOM. State changes in react are flushed later, and don't happen immediately. `useLayoutEffect` waits until the DOM change is committed.

Another way of doing it is by wrapping it in a `0` second timeout. This looks hackier than it is, as a timer with 0 as the time to wait, will just wait until the current call stack is finished before executing.

```
  const toggleInputCardName = () => {
    setInputCardNameVisibity(!isInputCardName)
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (inputRef.current) {
        console.log('YES inputRef.current', inputRef.current)
        inputRef.current.focus()
        inputRef.current.select()
      } else {
        console.log('NO inputRef.current', inputRef.current, isInputCardName)
      }
    }, 0)
  }
```

But I'd probably `useLayoutEffect`.

@OneQ answer of using the focus attribute also makes a lot of sense and reduces noise.